# Is there a mechanism for dealing with or discouraging malicious down voting?

Tags: feature-request, moderation

I've just seen a page where it would appear that someone has down voted every answer in one go.

Firstly: is this possible or is what I have just seen merely the coincidental occurrence of several people down-voting different answers at the same time? (If so please disregard the rest of this question)

Secondly: shouldn't there be some sort of mechanism in place (such as the 3 minute wait between proposed questions on the Area 51 stackexchange) to prevent such a thing?

Thirdly: would it be possible to enact some sort of penalty for down voting more than one answer on a page? - I was thinking the loss of rep points based on the fibonacci sequence for example (eg, 1st down-vote on a single post costs 1, 2nd on the same post = 3, 3rd = 5... or something like that

Comment: This is more of a global Stack Exchange issue than one specific to UX.Stackexchange, to be honest. And there are several questions on malicious downvoting over there that should give you some useful feedback. Such as: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164494/malicious-downvotes However, if there's a specific incident here you can flag the question itself and moderators can do some investigation to look into specific behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @JonW. The problem is that I don't actually know if there's a incident or just a coincidence. I'll go check the other board that you mentioned and come back and close this if necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer already appears on the main stackexchange meta board: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164494/malicious-downvotes

Answer (score 1):

So, for the sake of completeness, here's the answer.

There are automated scripts that detect this kind of behaviour and readjust the vote values within the next 12-24 hours.

More info here: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857)

Thanks to JonW for pointing me in the right direction